# ADFS and Office 365 integration with different domains

Tags: office365, adfs2.0

I need to integrate office 365 account(which has primary domain lets say abc.com) and my ADFS server for single sign on. My ADFS server is accessible by url https://adfs1.mydomain.com (it has domain mydomain.com).

Can I integrate both with different domains or both must have same domain for integration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically, they have the same domain so that the UPN match.

Otherwise, you need to add an alternate domain name - [Office 365 – Why Your UPN Should Match Your Primary SMTP Address](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/07/office-365-why-your-upn-should-match-your-primary-smtp-address/).

There is a deployment readiness tool that you can run across AD and it advises on the required steps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. Office365 only needs to know which STS it should go to when user@abc.com enters his username. If you configure it to go to https://adfs1.mydomain.com then it would go to the STS and tell the user to enter credentials there. Your STS should be able to handle the authentication of user@abc.com, i.e. it must have account directory for abc.com added in it.